# Get Individual phone number outbound sms usage/ logs

Tags: php, twilio-php

I am trying to get outbound sms logs against each individual phone number configured in twilio sub-account. I am using PHP programming language and looked into the api console:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-records

But according to my exploration, usage-record api only returns total usage information against my twilio account. i.e. 500 outbound sms against all the three subscribed numbers in my account say N1, N2 and N3.  What I want here is to retrieve the number of sms sent and received individually against each number N1, N2 and N3. Please help me in this regard.

Thanks

I have already did like this.

```
$sub_acc = $client->accounts->get($sub_account->sid);
$numbers = $sub_acc->incoming_phone_numbers;
$phone_sms_count = array();
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    $sms_count = 0;
    foreach ($sub_acc->messages->getIterator(0, 50, array(
        "From" => $number->phone_number,
        "DateSent" => $last_six_months_date)) as $sms)
        {
            $sms_count++;
        }
    $phone_sms_count[$number->phone_number] = $sms_count;
}
```

But it takes too much time to calculate sms counts for each number. I have configured 5 numbers in single subaccount and I have 10 subaccounts
this will break the limits.
Is there any way to get sms counts for each phone number without iterating messages?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you received downvotes but to me the question is legit so I'll try to help.

You can use the [Message API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#list) List Resource. Just filter the date range and from phone number. So to get records for last month (May 2016) just filter like:

```
// Set options
$from_number="XXXXXXXXXX"; 
$start_date="2016-05-01";
$end_date="2016-05-31";

// Build the option array
$get_iterator_options = array(
   'from' => $from_number,
   'DateSent' => $start_date,
   'DateSent' => $end_date
);

// Make the call with our options
foreach ($client->account->message->getIterator(
        0,
        50, 
        $get_iterator_options
    ) as $message
) {
    $msg_ids[] = $message->sid; // 
}

echo count($msg_ids);
```

Twilio provides a List Resource for Messages, Calls, Recordings, etc..

Keep in mind this is almost certainly slower than what you were trying to do originally especially if there are a lot of messages.

Comment: Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subaccount for each subscribed number ([documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts)). You can then retrieve total usage per subaccount.

Comment: I have multiple numbers against single sub account, and I need to track usage log against each.

Comment: @Smith if you need to track usage for each number then create a subaccount for each number

Comment: I have already created sub-account but my sub-account has 4 numbers, so now what to do?